# help on sorting a file using sort

Tags: bash, sorting

I have this file:

```
100: pattern1
++++++++++++++++++++
1:pattern2
9:pattern2
+++++++++++++++++++
79: pattern1
61: pattern1
+++++++++++++++++++
```

and I want to sort it like this:

```
++++++++++++++++++++
1:pattern2
9:pattern2
+++++++++++++++++++
61:pattern1
79:pattern1
100:pattern1
+++++++++++++++++++
```

Is it possible using Linux sort command only ?

If I had :

```
4:pat1 
3:pat2
2:pat2
1:pat1
```

O/p should be:

```
1:pat1
++++++++++++ 
2:pat2
3:pat2
++++++++++++
4:pat1
```

So,  want to sort on first group, but "group" on the pattern of second group.
Please note, the thing after : is a regex pattern not a literal.

Comment: What is the criteria for the first and second group?

Comment: I understand that you are trying to group lines depending on what comes after ':', and output a separator line between groups, but I do not understand how you want groups to be sorted. Are you assuming that the range of numerical values before ':' will never overlap between groups? That is, if you have "1:a", "2:b", "3:b" and "4:a", do you want to get the "a"s first or the "b"s first?

Comment: why the 1st 100 comes into second group? What are the sorting criteria? By the text following the number? so "1000:wow" will come into 1st group and "1:this is it" into second?

Comment: It seems like you'd be better off inserting the `++++`s yourself after walking through each line after a sort and you see that the value after `:` has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe `sort` alone can do what you need.

Create a new shell script and put this in its contents (ie `mysort.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n' # This makes the for loop below split on newline instead of whitespace.
delim=+++++++++++++++++++
for l in `grep -v ^+| sort -g`      # Ignore all + lines and sort by number
do
    current=`echo $l | sed s/^[0-9]*://g` # Get what comes after the number
    if [ ! -z "$prev" ] && [ "$prev" != "$current" ] # If it has changed...
    then                                  #  then output a ++++ delimiter line.
        echo $delim
    fi
    prev=$current
    echo $l                               # Output this line.
done
```

To use it, pipe in the contents of your file like so:

```
cat input | sh mysort.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Best you can do is to sort it according to the numerical values. But you cannot do anything with the "+"-string.

```
$ sort -n input
+++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++
1:wow
9:wow
61: this is it
79: this is it
100: this is it
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not -- it's not in the sort of format *sort(1)* expects.  And if you did it would be one of those amazing hacks, not easily used.  If you have some sort of rule for what goes between the lines of plus signs, you can do it readily enough with an AWK or Perl or Python script.

Answer (score 0):

If your input was space delimited, not ':' delimited:

```
sort  -rk2 | uniq -D -f1
```

will do the grouping;

- I guess you'd need to sort the 'subsections' later (unfortunately my `sort(1)` doesn't do composite key ordering. I do believe there are version that allow you to do `sort -k2,1n` and you'd be done at once).
- use `--all-repeated=separate` instead of `-D` to get blank separators between groups. Look at `man uniq` for more ideas!

However, since your input is colon delimited, a hack is required:

```
sed 's/\([0123456789]\+\):/\1 /' t | sort  -rk2 | uniq -D -f1
```

HTH